# Open .txt file with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am confused why this simple notepad file called common.txt is not opening. I am wondering is notepad is able to be used in python.

So I am trying to say whether the file exists:

```
import os.path
import sys

def file_exist(common):

#test whether the file exists and open it to a data structure

    if os.path.isfile(common):
       return common

    else:
        return

def main():
    common = input("enter: ")
    print(file_exist(common))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I did this identical code with a csv file and it seemed to work.

Output is:

```
enter: common.txt
None
```

Comment: You're sure you have the right path?

Comment: Show your output of an "ls" or "dir" as well as how you ran your program.

Comment: Edit the question to show us how you're running the program, and what it printed.

Comment: There is nothing in your program that opens a file. You are only working with the filename.

Comment: @KlausD.  I want to see if it exists first then open I but it says it doesn't exists when it does

Comment: Can you post the error that is being produced when you run the code.?

Comment: There is no error when I run this code, just gives me the else and not the if. When I do os.path.isfile("common.txt") it returns false which is shouldn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code worked fine for me.

I saved it as common.py, then ran it from the command line in the directory where common.py is located.

Here's the session:

```
C:\temp\so> python common.py
enter: common.py
common.py
```

The code does the following:
- Requests input
- If the input is a filename in the working directory, it prints out the filename.
- If the input is not a filename in the working directory, it outputs None.

Is there something else you want this code to do?

Comment: This is what I get. enter: common.txt
None

Comment: I want the a user to input a filename, so the directory will be different from theirs to mine.

Comment: Then there is no such file in your current working directory.

Comment: But I have the file saved in my downloads

Comment: Is your .py and .txt file in downloads ? If so then your code will work.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by your .py, but .txt is in my downloads file.

Comment: fixed it, the file was actually in another folder but in downloads. I moved the files out of the folder into the downloads and it worked.